# How to add to a table header dynamic datarow that will work with pagination?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to implement table with dynamic data and pagination, it works more or less fine but I do not know how to implement the same in header of my table dynamic data. In my case, it should be in days of the year.

The idea is to change the date in every page header and show new date for every week. It should also work with "previous" and "next" links. As I understand I should set a start and end date, but how can I really bind it with my table?

Here is an Example:

https://codepen.io/Dimi98765/pen/WNrxvPj

```js
thead += '<th style="padding:5px">' + "30.12.2019" + '</th>';
thead += '<th style="padding:5px">' + "31.12.2019" + '</th>';
thead += '<th style="padding:5px">' + "01.01.2020" + '</th>';
thead += '<th style="padding:5px">' + "02.01.2020" + '</th>';
thead += '<th style="padding:5px">'  + "03.01.2020" + '</th>';
thead += '<th style="padding:5px">'  + "04.01.2020" + '</th>';
thead += '<th style="padding:5px">' + "05.01.2020" + '</th></tr>';
tab.append(thead);

//Row is updated by:
function rowDisplay(startIndex, endIndex) {
    $('#paginate tr').hide().slice(startIndex, endIndex).show();
}
```

Comment: You have only updated the tr column when paging. You also need to access and update the table headers. For the tr columns, you have rendered every possible weekday. You could do the same with the headers, i.e. render them only when paginated.